# How to get one row to always display (using one view)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following (much simplified) view:

```
SELECT        T1.item, T2.text
FROM            T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         T2 ON T1.code = T2.code AND T1.item = T2.item
WHERE        (T1.item = '12345') AND (T1.code = '678') AND (T2.detailID = '99')
```

T1

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════════════╗
║ code  ║ item  ║ other info... ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════════════╣
║ code1 ║ item1 ║ other info... ║
║ code2 ║ item2 ║ other info... ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════════════╝
```

T2

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════════╦═══════╦═══════════════╗
║ code  ║ item  ║ detailID  ║ text  ║  other info   ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════════╬═══════╬═══════════════╣
║ code1 ║ item1 ║ detailID1 ║ text1 ║ other info... ║
║ code1 ║ item1 ║ detailID2 ║ text2 ║ other info... ║
║ code1 ║ item1 ║ detailID3 ║ text3 ║ other info... ║
║ code2 ║ item2 ║ detailID1 ║ text4 ║ other info... ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════════╩═══════╩═══════════════╝
```

NB: `detailID` is reused on multiple codes/items

In most instances this works fine. Except that on some occasions, `detailID` 99 does not exist for a code and item. When that happens, it returns 0 rows (I thought the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` would fix that but my SQL is very amateurish). How can I get it so it does return a row, but with just

```
12345, ''
```

as the result in that instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move the condition on the second table to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT T1.item, T2.text
FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     T2
     ON T1.code = T2.code AND T1.item = T2.item AND T2.detailID = '99'
WHERE (T1.item = '12345') AND (T1.code = '678') ;
```

When there is no match, then the value is `NULL` and your original `where` clause filters it out.

Comment: 1 second faster... :)

Comment: So obvious now I've seen it (had a feeling it might be!). Thanks :) (will mark as answer in 11 minutes)